# Is there a way to import 10, 20 or 100K records into firestore for testing?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, automated-tests

I'd like to test performance in my firebase app.  Is there a way to import thousands of dummy records into firestore for performance testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a HTTP Cloud Function to pass the number of dummy values you want to create:

This is an example to add Users, you can adapt it according to your needs. Running the writes individually and collecting with a `Promise.all()` allows then to run in parallel, potentially speeding up execution.

```
exports.addDummyUsers = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

        let dbb = admin.firestore();
        let counter = request.query.counter;

        const promises = []

        for (let i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
            promises.push(
                dbb.collection('Users').doc('Lone' + i).set({
                    email: 'Dummy',
                    name: 'Dummy',
                    phoneNumber: 'Dummy'
                })
            )
        }

        return Promise.all(promises)
            .then(resultsArray => {
                response.send(counter + ' Dummy Values Created!');
            })
            .catch(error => {
            });

});
```

You can also take a look into the [official video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA&t=1s&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLkPZHe41m4jfAxUi0JjLgSM&index=3).

Answer (score 0):

You can write code to add the dummy documents that you want.  There isn't any off-the-shelf tool that will automatically generate exactly what you need.